# simple javascript increment doesn't work? (Actually, Protractor issue not javascript)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

simple JavaScript counter is not working.

I am using JavaScript within protractor (angular testing framework) but I don't think it's the protractor issues but JavaScript issues.

I thought that I can do this: (pseudo code actual code is the one below)

```
var counter = 0

foreach (smallitems in bigitems){
    function(smallitems){foreach (item in smaillitems){
        if(item == "somevalue") counter++ }
    }
}
```

#### but counter never grows evenwhen there's matching values.

Actual codes are:

```
'use strict';

describe('list page ', function () {

    it('should list page', function() {

        var counter = 0;

        element.all(by.repeater('page in pages')).each(function (page) {
            element.all(by.repeater('item in items')).each(function (item) {
                if (item.getText() == ("A+")) {
                    counter++;
                }
            })
        })
    })
})
```

#### counter always 0. Do you see the problem here?

thank you!

Comment: Did you check by `alert` or `console.log` that increment part is actually executed?

Comment: `foreach` is wrong. The structure is `for (var x in object)` in JavaScript. You're confusing it with `myArray.forEach(function (d) {/*do something */})`

Comment: Missing closing brackets here for `if` and `foreach` -> `for`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/how-to-do-for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript

Answer (score 3):

`item.getText()` is a webdriver Promise [Object object] so it will never `== "A+"`

You need to follow promises when not using `expect`. The reason why `expect(item.getText()).toEqual("A+")` would work is because `expect` resolves promises for you and performs the string comparission with "A+" in this case.

Moving back to the issue at hand, it looks like you're trying to count things to perform an expectation on the total count:

```
describe('count on filtered elements', function() {
    // page objects
    var pagesRepElms = element.all(by.repeater('page in pages'));
    var itemsLocator = by.repeater('item in items');

    // since Protractor 1.3 more interesting page objects can be stored
    var aPlusElms = pagesRepElms.all(itemsLocator).filter(function(item) {
        return item.getText().then(function(text) {
            return text === 'A+';
        });
    });

    it('gathers and performs the count expectation in 1 line', function() {
      // modify 5 with your expected count
      expect(aPlusElms.count()).toEqual(5);
    });
});
```

Comment: I don't have time to try this out at the moment. but getting strong feeling this is IT!. may I ask you where did you spot "// this need to be here if you want to preserve state between it() specs "? Is there docs I am missing :) Big thank you.

Comment: That's not in the docs but is how Jasmine works regarding scope and expectations on top of promises. I've simplified the answer to the best solution, good luck ;)

Answer (score 1):

First you need to fix your missing closing brackets. `foreach` should just be `for`. And inside our `for` loop we say: `smaillitems[item]` and not just `item`. Same for the outer loop. Finnaly we don't want to use `function`, that's defines a new function, it's not called, so we don't need it:

```
for (smallitems in bigitems) {
    for (item in bigitems[smallitems]) {
        if(bigitems[smallitems][item] == "somevalue"){ counter++; }
    }
}
```

Comment: whoops sorry. I was pseudo coding. (at least for the first one) which I believe contains the same logic as one below. strangely though, the one at the bottom never increments the counter.

Comment: Just fixed, I should of said `bigitems[smallitems][item]` when I said `smallitems[item]`.

Comment: Thanks for showing me the correct way. and yet as for the protractor one, it doesn't accept the logic you game me. I was searching for the logic behind and wasn't successful.

Comment: It seems to be working in this fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/ef9aaaf2/1/. Note I didn't say `var counter = 0;` above.

Comment: I checked to the point that there are actually matching elements (that item.getText() == ("A+") becomes true) among items.

Comment: I tried out working sample within my protractor setting. it throws errors saying bigitems is not defined. One thing more, I am user 'use strict'; mode

Comment: @CodeSchoolJJ Where/how did you define `bigitems`?

Comment: bigitems is within "describe", "it" function blocks (jasmine framework requires these blocks and the same for the protractor). So my javascript is within the function block and this make things bit more complicated.

Comment: Can you explicitly define a `bigitems = [...]` for testing purposes and see if that works?

Comment: yes I checked the array and that it's matching becomes true. ) ( this part: item.getText() == ("A+")) for the bigitems example, I cannot use without var bigitems. thank you again. might need to leave it for now :) * I edited original code bit more